# Typing in Live-Rendered Markdown

Tags: markdown, previewing

I know there are ways to preview markdown as you type but is there a way to avoid this duplication of text (rendered and pain text in different buffers)?

Basically, I want to type in the preview. What I'm looking for goes like this:

As I type in

```
# Headline
```

, the characters making up the word "Headline" already are being rendered so I see

> ## Hea

and as I type a "d", it changes to:

> ## Head

Or some other convenient way of rendering it live without duplication, for example in every line but the one the pointer is currently in.

Comment: What exactly does duplication mean? Are you referring to having an extra buffer open with the rendered contents, next to a buffer with the text?

Comment: Yes. I'll add this to clarify.

Comment: Not as far as I know. [`markdown-mode`](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) *sort of* does this by adjusting the size of titles. More extensive rendering is more like what [AucTeX does for LaTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/img/preview-screenshot.png).

Comment: I'd also love to see this, but including the leading `#`, just like https://github.com/brrd/Abricotine does.

Comment: The (commercial) software [Typora](https://typora.io/#feature) is such an editor. It works reasonably well. I'd like something similar in Emacs. @TobiasKienzler I tried Abricotine and it does only what so many other Markdown editors do (i.e. show both the markup and its effect). What's being asked for here (e.g. what Typora does) is to show *only* the effect of the markup (except for a small region around where one is typing). For example, if one types `*italics*` then (except when the cursor (point in Emacs) is inside that region), one simply sees italicized text, and *not* the asterisks.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I didn't actually find _that_ many other Markdown editors which show the (mostly) rendered Markdown in the editor itself instead of a side-by-side view, and if I remember correctly Abricotine was the only one that also manages to render LaTeX maths.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Oh I see, thank you for explaining. Anyway, how to achieve either of these effects in Emacs, which is what drew us here I guess, remains open...